# Why am I getting an integer (type) error when I am not using an integer when looping?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a solution below to the TwoSumsII problem, where we basically have a list of sorted integers, and a target, and we want to return all set of 2 numbers that add up to the target:

```
nums = [2,7,11,15]
target = 18

comp= dict()          
  
for i in range(len(nums)-1):
    comp = target - nums[i]     
    if nums[i] in comp:
        print(comp[nums[i],i])

    else:
        print("Target cannot be reached")
```

For some reason, I am getting the error for the `if nums[i] in comp:`
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable.

I don't understand this error, because I don't see what is an integer in this line of code?- is it `nums[i]`  that is an integer?

Also, I have a question about the use of dict() in this solution. Am I right in saying that we are using a dictionary, which provides a way to store 'key'-'value' pairs? And in this case, the 'key' is the index of each number in the list and the `value` is comp, where `comp = target - nums[i]`  ?

Comment: comp is an integer value, so you cannot iterate over comp, that's where the error comes from

Comment: Check online, how to create a dictionary in Python

Comment: "because I don't see what is an integer in this line of code?- is it nums[i] that is an integer?" Well, there are two things that you could possibly consider: `nums[i]`, and `comp`. Did you try *checking* what the values are? Did you try reasoning it out? For example, when you do `for x in y`, which of `x` and `y` do you think is normally *expected* to be iterable? Therefore, which thing do you think will be a problem if it's an `int`?

Comment: "Am I right in saying [fundamentals about what a `dict` is in Python...]" Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation. If you don't understand this sort of thing already, you should be looking for and following a tutorial from the beginning.

Comment: Think carefully about the line of code in question. What is the purpose of the test? Therefore, what value should you be checking for, and where should you be checking for it? Hint: what are the two values in your program that are supposed to add to your `target`? What is the thing that they are both supposed to come from? Do you already know that one of them is from there? (Hint, yes, you do, because you explicitly took it from there.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your identifier `comp` is initially a dictionary, and then you assign it an integer in the line

```
comp = target - nums[i]
```

As @Cute Panda pointed out, you can't iterate over an integer.

> Am I right in saying that we are using a dictionary, which provides a
> way to store 'key'-'value' pairs?

Yes. That's what dictionaries do in general.

> And in this case, the 'key' is the index of each number in the list
> and the value is comp, where comp = target - nums[i] ?

No! Because you are never adding anything to the dictionary itself. In fact, in each iteration, you are assigning a new integer value to the variable comp which was a dictionary. So in the for loop, there is no dictionary at all!

Look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary/) on how to add key-value pairs to a dictionary.

Furthermore, I don't believe ***your*** solution would work without a second for loop. Either you could do a binary search (since the array is sorted) for the integer comp, or linear-search for it using another for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
nums = [2,7,11,15]
target = 18

comp= dict()            
                      
for i in range(len(nums)-1):
    comp[i] = target - nums[i]     

    if comp[i] == nums[i+1]:
        print(i,i+1)
```

I've found a solution, and it seems to work!